# Concurrent Bubble sort in golang

Tags: sorting, go, concurrency, bubble-sort

Can someone explain to me how the goroutine works in the following code, I wrote it btw.

When I do BubbleSortVanilla, it takes roughly 15s for a list of size 100000
When I do BubbleSortOdd followed by BubbleSortEven using the odd even phase, it takes roughly 7s. But when I just do ConcurrentBubbleSort it only takes roughly 1.4s.

Can't really understand why the single ConcurrentBubbleSort is better?
Is it cause of the overhead in creating the two threads and its also processing the
same or well half the length of the list?

I tried profiling the code but am not really sure how to see how many threads are being created or the memory usage of each thread etc

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func BubbleSortVanilla(intList []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(intList)-1; i += 1 {
        if intList[i] > intList[i+1] {
            intList[i], intList[i+1] = intList[i+1], intList[i]
        }
    }
}

func BubbleSortOdd(intList []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan []int) {
    for i := 1; i < len(intList)-2; i += 2 {
        if intList[i] > intList[i+1] {
            intList[i], intList[i+1] = intList[i+1], intList[i]
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func BubbleSortEven(intList []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(intList)-1; i += 2 {
        if intList[i] > intList[i+1] {
            intList[i], intList[i+1] = intList[i+1], intList[i]
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func ConcurrentBubbleSort(intList []int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan []int) {
    for i := 0; i < len(intList)-1; i += 1 {
        if intList[i] > intList[i+1] {
            intList[i], intList[i+1] = intList[i+1], intList[i]
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    // defer profile.Start(profile.MemProfile).Stop()
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    intList := rand.Perm(100000)
    fmt.Println("Read a sequence of", len(intList), "elements")

    c := make(chan []int, len(intList))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    start := time.Now()
    for j := 0; j < len(intList)-1; j++ {
        // BubbleSortVanilla(intList) // takes roughly 15s

        // wg.Add(2)
        // go BubbleSortOdd(intList, &wg, c)  // takes roughly 7s
        // go BubbleSortEven(intList, &wg, c)

        wg.Add(1)
        go ConcurrentBubbleSort(intList, &wg, c) // takes roughly 1.4s
    }
    wg.Wait()
    elapsed := time.Since(start)

    // Print the sorted integers
    fmt.Println("Sorted List: ", len(intList), "in", elapsed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working at all. `ConcurrentBubbleSort` and `BubbleSortOdd` +  `BubbleSortEven` will cause the data race. Try to run your code with `go run -race main.go`. Because of data race, data of array will be incorrect after sort, and they are not sorted neither.

Why it is slow? I guess it is because of data race, and there are too many go routines which are causing the data race.

> The Thread Analyzer detects data-races that occur during the execution
> of a multi-threaded process. A data race occurs when:
>
> 1. two or more threads in a single process access the same memory
>    location concurrently, and
> 2. at least one of the accesses is for writing, and
> 3. the threads are not using any exclusive locks to control their
>    accesses to that memory.